# Как выводить три разных случайных числа снова и снова?

Tags: javascript, jquery, случайные-числа, setinterval

Есть такой скрипт для получения трёх случайных чисел и их постоянного обновления:

```js
var random = 1000;

$('.qqq').each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    setInterval(function () {
        random = randomizator(60000, 200000);
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        showRandom(random, element);
    }, random);
})

function randomizator(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * b) + a;
}

function showRandom(random, element) {
    element.text(random);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="qqq"></div>
<div id="test2" class="qqq"></div>
<div id="test3" class="qqq"></div>
```

и он прекрасно работает. Но стоит мне уменьшить дипазон значений, как сразу же начинает выводить одинаковые значения во всех трёх: `1 1 1`, `4 4 4` и т.д.

Мне нужно, чтобы числа были все разные, а не три одинаковых. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться начинающему разработчику.

Comment: Если вам ответ помог - надо отметить его такой зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно запускать много  таймеров – по одному на каждый найденный элемент. Они могут разбегаться и тогда начинаются глюки с тем, что не тот элемент получает установленное в вашу общую переменную `random` значение.

Достаточно одного таймера, и обновлять всю обойму элементов.

Обновлённый вариант кода для нескольких независимых таймеров. Ф-я `update()` получает параметром комплект элементов, в которых она должна обновить значения на случайные:

```js
var $el1 = $('.class-1');
var $el2 = $('.class-2');
var a = 1E2, b = 1E3; // случайные от и до

function update( $el) {
  for( var i=0; i<$el.length; i++) {
    $( $el[i]).text( a + Math.floor( Math.random() * (b - a)));
  }
}

setInterval( function(){ update( $el1);}, 800);
setInterval( function(){ update( $el2);}, 1200);
```

```css
body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;} div {margin:2px; width: 100px; text-align:center;}
.class-1 { background-color: #FCA }
.class-2 { background-color: #CAF }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-1"></div>
<div class="class-1"></div>
<div class="class-1"></div>

<div class="class-2"></div>
<div class="class-2"></div>
<div class="class-2"></div>
```

Comment: вот прям в точку! спасибо!

Comment: Но не могли бы вы мне подскзаать, как сделать что бы на следуйщие допустим 5ть чисел интервал другой был? ( ну т.е. вот первая строка идет с этим скриптом) а вторую надо что бы генировались каждый час допустим. мне нужно просто изменить class?

Comment: Другой класс; новая отдельная переменная как сейчас `els` с выборкой по этому *другому* классу; и копия функции `update()`, использующая эту *новую* переменную. И другое значение в `setInterval()` для этой *копии* `update()`. Это немного «костыльно», надо бы сделать красивее/правильнее, раз требуется несколько независимых таймеров. Но это уже отдельный вопрос )

Comment: а если не сложно не могли бы привести пример js для новго класса дабы до конца понять какие элементы меняются, даже если это будет "костыльно")

Comment: И вообще , возможно ли что бы при обновлении страници рандом не срабатывал. а числа генерировались бы только в указанный имим инетрвал?

Comment: Обновил ответ бескостыльным решением. Так можно сколько угодно разных интервалов запустить для элементов разных классов.

Comment: update где именно убрать, что свехру что с низу убираю прекращает давать числа.

Comment: Зачем убирать – в ответе уже финальный вариант кода. Нажмите синюю кнопку «Выполнить код».